# How do I sum a column, and join it to another table based on a condition in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in SQL, one that contains product_id, products_name, department_name, and product_sales and one that has department_id, department_name, and over_head_costs.

I want to be able to find the sum of all sales (grouped by department_name in table 1) and subtract the over_head_costs from table 2 so that I know how profitable a department is. Then I want to output the information like:
department_id, department_name, over_head_costs, product/department sales, total_profit.

I've been searching for like 2-3 hours. I've messed around with joins (which I'm pretty sure is how to solve this) and found the SUM function, which achieves summing (but not by department) and honestly, even if I'd seen the solution I wouldn't know it. I'm just really struggling to understand SQL.

```
SELECT SUM(products.product_sales), department_id, departments.department_name, over_head_costs 
FROM products, departments 
WHERE products.department_name = departments.department_name;
```

This is my most recent query and the closest I've gotten, except it only returns one department (I currently have 3).

This is roughly what I’d like it to look like:

Table 1 (products):

```
ID    ITEM         DEPARTMENT                SALES

1      Hammer       Tools                     40

2.     Nails        Tools                     40

3.     Keyboard     Computer                  80
```

Table 2 (departments):

```
ID    DEPARTMENT    COST

1      Tools        20 

2.     Computer     30
```

Output:

```
ID    DEPARTMENT    COST     SALES      PROFIT

1       Tools       20         80               60

2.      Computer    30         80               50
```

I'm not really sure what else to try. I think I'm just not understanding how joins and such work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data in a table format and a desired result based on it.

Comment: @peterm I edited it into the OP. Formatting kind of sucks but I hope it’s enough to get the idea across. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `SUM` wiht `group by` in a subquery. then do `join`.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT d.*,
       t1.SALES,
      (t1.SALES - d.COST)PROFIT
FROM (
    SELECT DEPARTMENT,SUM(SALES) SALES 
    FROM products
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENT
) t1 JOIN  departments d on d.DEPARTMENT = t1.DEPARTMENT
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e9d3a/2/0)**:

```
| DEPARTMENT | COST | SALES | PROFIT |
|------------|------|-------|--------|
|      Tools |   20 |    80 |     60 |
|   Computer |   30 |    80 |     50 |
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, but I finally got a chance to mess around with this query and it wasn't working. I was able to edit it to the following ```SELECT *
FROM (SELECT department_name, SUM(product_sales)SALES FROM products GROUP BY department_name) departments
JOIN departments ON departments.dept_name = department_name;```

Which partially worked but is duplicating some of the information, so the table looks like this:
```department_name | SALES | department_id | dept_name | over_head_costs
Tools                         36           1                       Tools             1500```